# running python selenium in docker-compose

Tags: python, selenium, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run python selenium in docker-compose. I have the following files:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - chrome
    ports:
      - '8443:8443'

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:3.14.0-gallium
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      HUB_HOST: hub

  hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.14.0-gallium
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM    python:latest
COPY    test.py /code/test.py
WORKDIR /code
RUN     pip install --upgrade pip
RUN     pip install pytest
RUN     pip install pytest-asyncio
RUN     pip install selenium
```

test.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor='http://hub:4444/wd/hub',
        desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME,
        )

print(driver)
```

I run:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose run python test.py
```

And I get a connection-refused error in test.py when trying to create the webdriver.

```
'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ffb3b34d550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')'
```

Looking at the logs, the hub and the chrome driver appear to be up and running and the chrome driver is connected to the hub. I can ping the hub and chrome containers from app. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a working version:
Also make sure to wait for hub to be ready link to be ready before testing:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#waiting-for-the-grid-to-be-ready

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  selenium-hub:
    restart: always
    image: selenium/hub:3.14.0
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"

 chrome:
    restart: always
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug:3.14.0
    ports:
      - "5900-5999:5900"
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      HUB_HOST: selenium-hub
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR: selenium-hub
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT: 4444
      DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS: "/dev/null"
    links:
      - selenium-hub:hub
```

Comment: Waiting for hub to be ready was the problem. I added a loop in my python script. Every time I run, I get a few seconds of connection refused errors, then `/wd/hub/status` returns not ready for about a second, and then it becomes ready and works! I also found that I have to run `docker-compose stop` between every test or else `/wd/hub/status` returns not ready forever...

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar setup and the only difference I can see is that you have not given the HUB_PORT arg under the chrome instance:

```
environment:
    HUB_HOST: hub
    HUB_PORT: 4444
```

Example I used to get setup is here: [SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#version-3)

Comment: Just tried this but no change. The logs show that the chrome driver successfully connects to the hub.

Comment: What is the ip you are trying to access via your test? Usually the error you mentioned appears when the endpoint you are trying to access doesn't exist/is not accessible.